# EditText с разделенной нижней линией

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Здравствуйте!

Не получилось нагуглить решение данной задаче. Подскажите кто знает, возможно ли кастомизировать `EditText` до такого вида, т.е. разделить нижнюю линию:

[image: Кастомный EditText]

или нужно, каким-то образом, обьеденять несколько `EditText`-ов, если да, то как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего Вам подойдет библиотека [PinEntryEditText](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3900):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не подходит, попробуйте поискать на [android-arsenal.com](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/207), с большой долей вероятности найдете что-нибудь подходящее.